# C# Path.GetExtension 'If' Statement

Tags: c#, winforms, if-statement, file-extension

My previous question was closed due to the fact that there are supposedly tied to *Path.GetExtension*.

Apparently, you may be able to get a file extension by Open Dialog using this function, however, may I know how to use Path.GetExtension in 'If' Statements/ 'If Statement'-like functions?

```
// SAMPLE CODE 1
OpenFileDialog1.Filter = "Image Files (JPG,PNG,GIF)|*.JPG;*.PNG;*.GIF";


// SAMPLE CODE 2
if (OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
   string ext = Path.GetExtension(OpenFileDialog1.FileName); 



// SAMPLE CODE 3
if(DialogResult.OK == saveDialog.ShowDialog())
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(saveDialog.FileName);

    switch(extension.ToLower())
    {
        case ".jpg":
            // ToDo: Save as JPEG
            break;
        case ".png":
            // ToDo: Save as PNG
            break;
        default:
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(extension);
    }
}
```

So in this case, how can this code be organized as to create if statements for different file extensions?

Comment: from your question , it is hard to guess what problem you want to solve.

Comment: Why do you need an `if` ? you are already using a `switch` ?

Comment: Do you mean converting the `switch` to a sequence of `if`s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
if(DialogResult.OK == saveDialog.ShowDialog())
{
    var extension = Path.GetExtension(saveDialog.FileName).ToLower();
    if (extension.Equals(".jpg"))
    {

    }
    else if (extension.Equals(".png"))
    {

    }
    else
    {      
       throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(extension);
    }
}
```

if this dos not help you please add more detail

Comment: Thank you, combined with my code this is it!